# Antoymn for slowcoach?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Hurry up and get ready for school.
>   Don't be a slowcoach! Be a ______ !

What fits in the _____ ? Hopefully something other than **fastcoach**!

I found [some old discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-antonym-of-slowpoke.581211/) 
 but nothing there seem to fit.

Slowcoach (BrE) = Slowpoke (US).

Comment: *Express coach*?

Comment: I remember 'Jehu' being used as an eponym many years ago. It is probably archaic, and was only used for fast travellers. See this article in [The Lost Words: A Feast of Forgotten Words, Their Origins and Their Meanings – Pete May, Philip Howard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=N_utAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=Jehu+eponym&source=bl&ots=TAP7slXlAI&sig=ZTgE7RmtHcaVVmxyEttIiFkZjhA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7jfSB79DNAhXlIsAKHaRbAhMQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=Jehu%20eponym&f=false).

Comment: There was a science fiction story about someone who could speed up by a large factor.  I can't remember anything else about it.

Comment: @ab2 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flash_(2014_TV_series) ?

Comment: @Kieran no, not from a TV series.  Definitely a story or novel.  I have posted a question on F&SF Stack Exchange http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133451/story-about-a-person-who-could-speed-up-temporarily  But maybe you've answered your own question with The Flash.

Comment: hotrod works in this neck of the woods.

Comment: Well, the person from the link you provided essentially answered your question. It's an idiom, so there are not going to be direct antonyms. But there are a lot of other idioms that mean the complete opposite. Just Google it and see if you spot something you like: https://www.google.com/#q=very+fast+idioms

Comment: Speed daemon.  Quick like a bunny/rabbit.

Comment: @Jim - I'd upvote Speed demon/daemon as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for 2 great  answers & helpful comments; I have a masterplan :-)  to use more positive (and less negative) encouragement in the mornings when getting my children ready for school and all these words will come in useful. I liked both answers but accepted the one with comic/cartoon references as my target audience is six years old !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Britain, you could probably get away with saying be a "***[Billy Whizz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Whizz)***".

Billy Whizz was a character from the comic "The Beano" and was known as "The World's fastest boy".

> You're going to be late for school; come on, Billy Whizz!

[image]

Another character from the small screen could be "***[Speedy Gonzalez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedy_Gonzales)***".

> You're making too many mistakes; slow down, Speedy Gonzalez!

Answer (score 2):

> Hurry up and get ready for school. Don't be a slowcoach! Be ______ !

1. **swift as an arrow**   *[(very fast)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/swift+as+the+wind)*
2. **swift as the wind** (ditto)
3. **faster than greased lightning** (*[extremely fast](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/faster+than+greased+lightning)*)
4. **faster than a speeding bullet** and **FTASB** ([*very fast*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/faster+than+a+speeding+bullet))